# Помогите решить задачу на питоне, пожалуйста. Два часа билась... и можно ли ее решить без функций мин и макс?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программа получает на вход число проехавших автомобилей N (1 > N > 30). Затем указываются их скорости. Значение скорости не может быть меньше 1 и больше 300. Программа должна сначала вывести разность максимальной и минимальной скоростей автомобилей, затем количество автомобилей, скорость которых не превышала 30 км/ч.

Comment: Можно. Эти функции тут вообще не требуются.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, собственные попытки, которые предпринимались целых 2 часа, и конкретные трудности, иначе вопрос не по теме сайта

Comment: дак я уже вс1 стерла, извините, что не по теме иногда...

Answer (score 2):

```
input() # skip N
l = map(int, input().split(' '))


min_velocity = 300
max_velocity = 1
less30 = 0
for x in l:
    if x > max_velocity:
        max_velocity = x
    if x < min_velocity:
        min_velocity = x
    if x <= 30:
        less30 += 1

print(max_velocity - min_velocity)
print(less30)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Получите массив скоростей;
2. Отсортируйте массив скоростей (или функцией `sorted` или методом `sort`), и у вас уже есть максимальная и минимальная скорость;
3. Пройдитесь по всем элементам отсортированного массива и подсчитайте сколько автомобилей имели скорость не больше 30 км/ч;

Comment: Можно и не сортировать. А если уж отсортировано, то не надо проходиться по всем числам.